# CDI producer method for JNDI resources

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Is it possible to use CDI for injecting JNDI resources with JNDI name known only at runtime?

I tried doing something like this:

```
public class InjectionClient {

     @Inject
     @Any
     Instance<MyJndiResource> anyResource;

     public MyJndiResource JndiResource() {
          MyJndiResource anyResource.select(new JndiQualifierLiteral(containerJndi)).get();
          //do stuff...
     }
}
```

where `MyJndiResource` is injected by a Producer method

```
public class MyJndiResourceProducer {

    @Produces
    @JndiQualifier("nonbinding")
    public MyJndiResource produceWorkerByContainerJndi(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        String jndi = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(JndiQualifier.class).value();

        return (MyJndiResource) new InitialContext().lookup(containerJndi));
}
```

But then I get NPE in the first line of the producer method. Probably, because the injectionPoint's annotations are based on the injection point of the `Instance` and not on the `Instance#select()` arguments.

The qualifier's jndi property is nonbinding:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER})
public @interface JndiQualifier {
     @Nonbinding
     String value();
}
```

and for completeness sake the `JndiQualifierLiteral` code:

```
public class JndiQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<JndiQualifier> implements JndiQualifier {

    private String jndi;

    public JndiQualifierLiteral(String jndi) {
        this.jndi = jndi;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
       return jndi;
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this, so that I can produce JNDI resources whose JNDI name is only known at runtime with CDI producers?

Comment: As by the way: anyResource.select(...) uses JndiQualifier instead of JndiQualifierLiteral.

Also, why would you use, in the produce, JndiQualifierLiteral.class, instead of JndiQualifier.class, what if you have different anonymous impl?

Comment: My mistake, I have rewritten it from some more complex code, now it is corrected, thank you.